# How to extract values based on keys from a list of `dict` objects in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, mapping

I have a list `sample_list` looks like this:

```
[{'ID': '123456', 'price': '1.111'}, {'ID': '987654', 'price': '200.888'}, {'ID': '789789', 'price': '0.212'},{..},...]
```

It contains multiple `dict` object, now I want to write a function that takes a list of `ID` as inputs and return the corresponding `price`, something like:

```
def mapping_data(ids: list) -> map:
    mapping_data['123456'] = '1.111
    return mapping_data
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `list_comprehension` with `if condition`:

```
def mapping_data(ids):
    return [d['price'] for id in ids for d in l if d['ID'] == id]
```

Complete code:

```
l = [{'ID': '123456', 'price': '1.111'}, {'ID': '987654',
                                          'price': '200.888'}, {'ID': '789789', 'price': '0.212'}]


def mapping_data(ids):
    return [d['price'] for id in ids for d in l if d['ID'] == id]


mapping_data(['987654', '123456']) #prints ['200.888', '1.111']
```

You can also use `dict_comprehension` if you need id details:

```
def mapping_data(ids):
    return {id:d['price'] for id in ids for d in l if d['ID'] == id}
# prints {'987654': '200.888', '123456': '1.111'}
```

Better Alternative:

1. `Dict_comprehension`:

```
def mapping_data(ids):
    return {i['ID']:i['price'] for i in l if i['ID'] in ids}


mapping_data(['987654', '123456'])
```